# HtmlPurifier prepending extra list item to all lists

Tags: php, html, htmlpurifier

I'm using a `bbcode parser` to first parse the `bbcode` into `HTML` and then I am passing it through `HtmlPurifier` with the default config and for some reason it is prepending an extra list item to my lists in the HTML.

Here is the HTML code **before** being passed to `HtmlPurifier`:

```
<strong>bold text</strong><br />
<em><strong>bold italic</strong></em><br />
<span style="text-decoration: underline"><strong>bold underline</strong></span><br />
<em><span style="text-decoration: underline"><strong>bold underline italic</strong></span></em><br />
<strong>bold striked</strong><br />
<em><span style="text-decoration: underline"><strong>bold italic underlined striked</strong></span><br />
<br />
italic text</em><br />
<br />
<span style="color: #9966ff">colored text</span><br />
<br />
<span style="text-decoration: underline"><em>italic underlined</em></span><br />
<br />
<span style="text-decoration: underline">underlined text</span><br />
<br />
<span style="text-decoration: line-through">striked text</span><br />
<br />
align left<br />
<br />
<div style="text-align: center">align center</div><br />
<br />
<div style="text-align: right"><span style="text-decoration: underline"><strong>align right bold underline</strong></span><br />
<br />
<div style="text-align: left"><a href="http://moo.com">a text link</a></div><br />
<div style="text-align: left"><a href="http://moo.com">[color=#9966ff]a colored text link[/color]</a><br />
<span style="color: #6699ff"><a href="http://moo.com">[b]a bold text link[/b]</a></span><br />
<span style="color: #333333"><br />
<span style="font-size: large"><strong>My List</strong></span></span><br />
<br />
<ul><br />
<li>Cat</li><br />
<li>Dog</li><br />
<li>Fish</li><br />
<li>Duck</li><br />
</ul><br />
<span style="font-size: large"><strong>My List 2</strong></span><br />
:)<br />
:&#039;(<br />
<ol><br />
<li><strong><span style="color: #666633">Car</span></strong></li><br />
<li><strong><span style="color: #666633">Bike</span></strong></li><br />
<li><strong><span style="color: #666633">Tram</span></strong></li><br />
<li><strong><span style="color: #666633">Bus</span></strong></li><br />
</ol><br />
<span style="font-size: large"><strong><br />
My List 3</strong></span><br />
<br />
<ol><br />
<li><a href="http://moo.com">Moo</a></li><br />
<li><a href="http://quack.com">Quack</a></li><br />
<li><a href="http://woof.com">Woof</a></li><br />
<li><a href="http://meow.com">Meow</a></li><br />
</ol><br />
</div><br />
</div><br />
<br />
<span style="font-size: large"><strong><br />
My List 4</strong></span><br />
<br />
<ul><br />
<li>Cat</li><br />
<li>Dog</li><br />
<li>Fish</li><br />
<li>Duck</li><br />
</ul>
```

Here is the HTML code **after** being run through `HtmlPurifier` (note that I have formatted this nicely as it also removes the line-breaks)

```
<strong>bold text</strong><br /><em><strong>bold italic</strong></em><br /><span style="text-decoration:underline;"><strong>bold underline</strong></span><br /><em><span style="text-decoration:underline;"><strong>bold underline italic</strong></span></em><br /><strong>bold striked</strong><br /><em><span style="text-decoration:underline;"><strong>bold italic underlined striked</strong></span><br /><br />
italic text</em><br /><br /><span style="color:#9966ff;">colored text</span><br /><br /><span style="text-decoration:underline;"><em>italic underlined</em></span><br /><br /><span style="text-decoration:underline;">underlined text</span><br /><br /><span style="text-decoration:line-through;">striked text</span><br /><br />
align left<br /><br />
<div style="text-align:center;">align center</div>
<br /><br />
<div style="text-align:right;">
    <span style="text-decoration:underline;"><strong>align right bold underline</strong></span><br /><br />
    <div style="text-align:left;"><a href="http://moo.com">a text link</a></div>
    <br />
    <div style="text-align:left;">
        <a href="http://moo.com">[color=#9966ff]a colored text link[/color]</a><br /><span style="color:#6699ff;"><a href="http://moo.com">[b]a bold text link[/b]</a></span><br /><span style="color:#333333;"><br /><span style="font-size:large;"><strong>My List</strong></span></span><br /><br />
        <ul>
            <li><br /></li>
            <li>Cat<br /></li>
            <li>Dog<br /></li>
            <li>Fish<br /></li>
            <li>Duck<br /></li>
        </ul>
        <br /><span style="font-size:large;"><strong>My List 2</strong></span><br />
        :)<br />
        :'(<br />
        <ol>
            <li><br /></li>
            <li><strong><span style="color:#666633;">Car</span></strong><br /></li>
            <li><strong><span style="color:#666633;">Bike</span></strong><br /></li>
            <li><strong><span style="color:#666633;">Tram</span></strong><br /></li>
            <li><strong><span style="color:#666633;">Bus</span></strong><br /></li>
        </ol>
        <br /><span style="font-size:large;"><strong><br />
        My List 3</strong></span><br /><br />
        <ol>
            <li><br /></li>
            <li><a href="http://moo.com">Moo</a><br /></li>
            <li><a href="http://quack.com">Quack</a><br /></li>
            <li><a href="http://woof.com">Woof</a><br /></li>
            <li><a href="http://meow.com">Meow</a><br /></li>
        </ol>
        <br />
    </div>
    <br />
</div>
<br /><br /><span style="font-size:large;"><strong><br />
My List 4</strong></span><br /><br />
<ul>
    <li><br /></li>
    <li>Cat<br /></li>
    <li>Dog<br /></li>
    <li>Fish<br /></li>
    <li>Duck<br /></li>
</ul>
```

Any idea why it is doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're passing lists like these to HtmlPurifier:

```
<ul><br />
<li>Cat</li><br />
<li>Dog</li><br />
<li>Fish</li><br />
<li>Duck</li><br />
</ul><br />
```

But a `<br />` element cannot be the immediate child of an `<ul>` or `<ol>` element: all children of those list elements have to be `<li>` elements. So, HtmlPurifier collapses the `<br />` elements that occur **after** `<li>` tags *into* the `li` elements, thus resulting in html like `<li>Cat<br /></li>`. However, there is no `<li>` tag for the first `<br />` tag to collapse into, so a list item is generated instead to accomodate it.

To fix, you'll have to make the BBCode parser output html like this instead:

```
<ul>
<li>Cat</li>
<li>Dog</li>
<li>Fish</li>
<li>Duck</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Ahh ok, makes sense. I guess the bbcode parser is turning new lines into `<br>` tags and hence that's why they end up on the list items. I'll have to try out some other bbcode parsers. Thanks!